# Associating route 53 Nameservers with GoDaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I am using GoDaddy as domain, & AWS for instances. I have created route 53, & it generated four DNS. should I replace the two default GoDaddy DNS with route 53? or I add four AWS DNS & also keep two DNS of GoDaddy?

how can I prevent Downtime with Fail-safe settings?

Comment: Your title is a bit backwards. You aren't mapping Route 53 to GoDaddy, you are mapping/pointing GoDaddy to Route53.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent downtime, first copy all DNS entries from GoDaddy to Route53.

To switch from using GoDaddy DNS name servers to Route53, in your GoDaddy account delete the 2 Name Server entries provided by GoDaddy, and add the 4 AWS name servers.